# Instantiating array of objects from JSON

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm quite new to Typescript so I imagine this is a pretty stupid question, but I have an array of JSON objects that I want to map to a `Panel` class.

When my `PanelsService` class is instantiated I also want to instantiate my array of `Panel` objects.

What I've got so far:

***PanelsService.ts***

```
import {Panel} from './panel';

declare var _: any;

export class PanelsService {

  public panels: Array<Panel>;
  public customPanels: Array<Panel>;

  constructor(private _http:Http) {
    this.panels = window['panels']['views'];
  }
}
```

From this, none of my `Panels` are being instantiated (I have a log in the constructor). Obviously I could loop over `window['panels']['views']` and do something like `this.panels.push(new Panel(myPanel)` but it seems like there must be a better way.

FWIW, my `Panel` class is just a load of properties and a constructor.

Comment: FYI: You can use the shorter `Panel[]` instead of `Array<Panel>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If datas inside `window['panels']['views']` are an array of Panel, you just need to cast it to make TypeScript happy:

```
this.panels = <Panel[]>(window['panels']['views']);
```

This will not changed anything for the generated javascript, but it will compile.
Note that it will never call the `Panel` constructor. Your object in `window['panels']['views']` are already instanciate, so it's just a cast.

Comment: Is there some kind of pattern I'm missing then if I want to instantiate a bunch of classes from JSON, apart from looping and pushing? It seems like that would be a fairly common use case - for example, when i instantiate the class I want to store an object on the instance that contains the original property values.

Comment: A JSON is a javascript object. It has been 'sort of' instanciated. If it looks like your desired object, you don't need to do much. You can always instanciate your own objects base on the JSON data if you need to, but it will require manual mapping yes. You can use function like .map() and .filter() if you don't want to push and loop.